# Using formik.isValid on Submit Button when Button is outside of Formik Component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, twitter-bootstrap, react-bootstrap, formik

My React app has a `react-bootstrap` Bootstrap Modal that contains a Formik form in `Modal.Body` and the submit button in `Modal.Footer`.

How can we allow the `disabled` attribute of the button inside `Modal.Footer` to accept the `formik.isValid` and `formik.dirty` values?

```
disabled={!(formik.isValid && formik.dirty)}
```

**More Complete Code**

```js
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';

import { Button, Modal, Form } from 'react-bootstrap';
import { Formik } from 'formik';


export function NicknameModal({show, handleClose}) {

    return (
        <Modal show={show} onHide={handleClose}>
            <Modal.Header closeButton>
                <Modal.Title>My Title</Modal.Title>
            </Modal.Header>
            <Modal.Body>
                <Formik
                    initialValues={{
                        nickname: '',
                    }}
                    onSubmit={(
                        values,
                        { setSubmitting }
                    ) => {
                        setSubmitting(true);x
                        handleClose();
                        setSubmitting(false);
                    }}
                >
                    {({values, errors, touched, handleChange, handleBlur, handleSubmit, isSubmitting, setFieldValue }) => (
                        <Form id="nicknameForm" onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
                            <Form.Group controlId="formNickname">
                                <Form.Label>Nickname</Form.Label>
                                <Form.Control type="text" name="nickname" onChange={handleChange} onBlur={handleBlur} value={values.nickname} />
                            </Form.Group>
                        </Form>  
                    )}
                </Formik>
            </Modal.Body>
            <Modal.Footer>
                <Button variant="primary" type="submit" form="nicknameForm">Apply</Button>
            </Modal.Footer>
        </Modal>
    )
}
```

Comment: You can't do using this using native `Formik` component. What you can do using [`useFormik`](https://formik.org/docs/api/useFormik) hook. I have stuck something like this before so wrote this [blog](https://dev.to/shubhamforu/understanding-formik-hooks-with-use-case-complex-438d). Check if that works. Here is direct [demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/formik-hooks-ktk0d)

Answer (score 4):

you can use useRef property of React to take Formik control outside of the Formik component. Please documentation for [innerRef](https://formik.org/docs/api/field#innerref) of Formik

```
import React, { useState, useEffect, useRef } from 'react';
import { Button, Modal, Form } from 'react-bootstrap';
import { Formik } from 'formik';


export function NicknameModal({show, handleClose}) {

    const formRef = useRef();

    return (
        <Modal show={show} onHide={handleClose}>
            <Modal.Header closeButton>
                <Modal.Title>My Title</Modal.Title>
            </Modal.Header>
            <Modal.Body>
                <Formik
                    initialValues={{
                        nickname: '',
                    }}
                    innerRef={formRef}
                    onSubmit={(
                        values,
                        { setSubmitting }
                    ) => {
                        setSubmitting(true);x
                        handleClose();
                        setSubmitting(false);
                    }}
                >
                    {({values, errors, touched, handleChange, handleBlur, handleSubmit, isSubmitting, setFieldValue }) => (
                        <Form id="nicknameForm" onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
                            <Form.Group controlId="formNickname">
                                <Form.Label>Nickname</Form.Label>
                                <Form.Control type="text" name="nickname" onChange={handleChange} onBlur={handleBlur} value={values.nickname} />
                            </Form.Group>
                        </Form>  
                    )}
                </Formik>
            </Modal.Body>
            <Modal.Footer>
                <Button variant="primary" type="submit" 
                 disabled={!(formRef.current.isValid && formRef.current.dirty)}
                 form="nicknameForm">Apply</Button>
            </Modal.Footer>
        </Modal>
    )
}
```

Answer (score -2):

the button would never work because it is outside the form, I refactored it just added the yup dependency, here is the test : https://codesandbox.io/s/ancient-dew-6e9thm

Comment: 1. `Object.keys(errors).length === 0 ? true : false` is the same as `Object.keys(errors).length === 0`
2. How does this answer the initial question?

Comment: here it is refactored and using correctly https://codesandbox.io/s/ancient-dew-6e9thm